# How to get Yahoo's woeid by location?

Tags: geolocation, yahoo, weather

```
// Get woeid by lati/long
            HttpGet hg = new HttpGet(
                        "http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=" + latlon + "&flags=J&gflags=R)");
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse weatherHR = hc.execute(hg);

            if (weatherHR.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    Utils.log("", "Location != HttpStatus.SC_OK");
                return null;
            }
```

I used this API and it work ok before, but It return a error since today, the HttpStatus.SC_OK is not OK. Has this API been closed? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's closed, give a look here:
http://soup.metwit.com/post/47181933854/an-alternative-to-yahoo-weather-api

Comment: Yahoo! weather APIs is DEAD at 3rd April, 2013.

Comment: Yahoo has moved to a paid [BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/) service but your alternative is also a paid service simply with a free trial offer until June.

Comment: @Cas We have 200 calls per ip that means that you can implement the service client-side for free, for n-clients, without authentication!  We are about to change it in a couple of day with some cool stuff and plans (free!)

Comment: metwit is closed as well

Answer (score 10):

Yahoo has moved to paid service called [BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/) but they do offer a non-commercial service:

> Non-Commercial usage of Yahoo Geo API's
>
> Yahoo! continues to fully support developer applications built on top of Placefinder and PlaceSpotter in non-commercial settings. Both services are available to you via YQL and rate limited to 2000 queries per table. Learn more about using the Placefinder and Placespotter YQL tables.

Using [Placefinder](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/free_YQL.html#table_pm) you can reverse lookup a latitude and longitude:

`http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D%2237.416275%2C-122.025092%22%20and%20gflags%3D%22R%22`

which can be converted into a json request:

`http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D%2237.416275%2C-122.025092%22%20and%20gflags%3D%22R%22&format=json`

Answer (score 1):

A `city` can also be used as `location` as follows:

```sql
select * 
from weather.forecast 
where woeid in (
    select woeid 
    from geo.places(1) 
    where text="frankfurt"
) and u="c"
```

Where `"frankfurt"` can be replaced with any location of choice.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Yahoo Weather WOEID by latitude and longitude, you can use this

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22(20,34)%22%20limit%201&diagnostics=false&format=json
```

And you will receive a response like the following:

```
{
  "query":{
    "count":1,
    "created":"2017-03-17T20:34:50Z",
    "lang":"es-AR",
    "results":{
      "place":{
        "woeid":"1435509"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If still someone need answear. You have basic URL:

> https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=

Now you have to make correct YQL statement (replace city with your city name) e.x.

> select * from geo.places where text="city"

Now you have to encode to URI. You can use javascript method: encodeURIComponent().
Then you have to merge basicURL and encoded YQL statement and

> &format=json

So example of the whole link for San Francisco will be:

> http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22san%20francisco%2C%20ca%22&format=json

Now from response you have to get WOEID number. You can get it by:
**query>results>place>[0]>woeid**

So in Javascript it will be something like:

```
const woeidNumber = responseObject['query']['results']['place'][0]['woeid'];
```