# Yahoo Weather Query by Latitude and Longitude

Tags: yql, yahoo-weather-api

I want to fetch some weather data via latitude and longitude using yahoo query. but it seems this query is not available now. the query is below:

```
select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (SELECT woeid FROM geo.placefinder WHERE text="{lat},{lon}" and gflags="R")
```

is this query is changed to new one or something? or it didn't exist anymore? last time I use this format was about 2 months ago and it worked well. but now it can't fetch any data. result from YQL console is as below:

```
{
 "error": {
  "lang": "en-US",
  "description": "Tenant &#x27;query_yahooapis_com&#x27; access to &#x27;Resource [tenantName=query_yahooapis_com, type=TABLE, name=geo.placefinder, locatorType=FILE, url=/home/y/share/manhattan/application/tenantBundles/yql_query_yahooapis_com_manhattan_v2/YQL-INF/restdefs/geo.placefinder.xml, useUrl=false]&#x27; is denied."
 }
}
```

I already make some research, including this post: [How to get Yahoo's woeid by location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784177/how-to-get-yahoos-woeid-by-location)

Is that true that yahoo already terminate this latitude longitude query for fetching weather?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the latest reply to [this answer](https://developer.yahoo.com/forums/#/discussion/7844/yql-geo-placefinder-is-now-shutdown%3D%3D), you should switch to the table `geo.places` and remove the `gflags="R"` part.
I tried it in the YQL console and it seems to work:

```
select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (SELECT woeid FROM geo.places WHERE text="(latitude,longitude)")
```

Comment: hi. thank you for reply. but seems your answer still produce the same result. i really think that this query is not valid anymore.

Comment: It doesn't produce the same results. I don't know how you tried it, but I just tried and everything works fine.

[take a look here and just press the test button](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+weather.forecast+where+woeid+in+(SELECT+woeid+FROM+geo.places+WHERE+text%3D%22%7Blat%7D%2C%7Blon%7D%22))

Comment: may i know, what the exact location you put, i mean the latitude and longitude that you are using for this query? yes i already try your test and it works. but it seems you only put 'lat' and 'lon' in the query.

Comment: Try this one, is New York:

`select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (SELECT woeid FROM geo.places WHERE text="(40.7141667,-74.0063889)")`

Comment: If this answer has been useful, could you please vote this? I suppose it's you that gave the answer a negative vote...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me(you should switch to the table geo.places(1)):

...

```
query = "SELECT * FROM weather.forecast " +
            "WHERE woeid in (" +
            "SELECT woeid " +
            "FROM geo.places(1) " +
            "WHERE text=\"(%1$s,  %2$s)\") " +
            "AND u='c'";
```

... and then:

```
query = String.format(query, location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
```