# Get weather data from Yahoo Weather API with Oauth 1.0

Tags: javascript, api, yql, yahoo-weather-api

I am developing a web portal consuming the Yahoo web service for the real-time temperature. I was using combined YQL query to fetch the weather data by latitude and longitude which was not bad:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.placefinder where text='lat,lon')&format=json
```

Since this January, the combined query did not work anymore. 
Therefore, I had to make two separate http requests in sequence to get the data.

1. Get woeid from lan, lon and appid
2. Get data from woeid

It is quite time-consuming and less efficient to fetch the data from Yahoo each time. I have been googled a while for a solution to improve this but most of them are for old Yahoo weather API versions. 
I am looking for an way to shorten the time or some other mainstream free weather service providers, offering world weather.

**Update (2016.03.24)**

I found a way to make the combined YQL work from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220361/yahoo-weather-query-by-latitude-and-longitude?rq=1).

Change the YQL to:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.placefinder where text='(lat,lon)')&format=json
```

Just need to add brackets round the geo location. The previous one used to work util recently.

**Update (2016.03.25)**

The yahoo weather service was down yesterday and the YQL was invalid for quite a  while. 
From it official document, it says that it had enforced Oauth 1 since March 15 via the url https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=...
Even though the public link was back today, I found that I was unable to switch weather unit by adding u='c' or u='f'.

*I don't know whether Yahoo weather API will continue to maintain the old url or not. For the time being, it is still alive.
I am looking forward to a solution to query Yahoo weather by Oauth 1.0 in Javascript.*

Comment: openweathermap.org may be an alternative

Comment: The old public URL doesn't work anymore (as of april 2016). Have to use oauth now.

Comment: @SujayPhadke til now, I am still using the old URL. I don't know when it would get invalid.